# Returning a list of indices where a certain object appears in a nested array

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

I am trying to figure out how to form an array that collects every index of a particular object (in this case a single letter) where it appears in a nested set of arrays. For instance, using the array set below,

```
boggle_board = [["P", "P", "X", "A"], 
                ["V", "F", "S", "Z"],
                ["O", "P", "W", "N"],
                ["D", "H", "L", "E"]]
```

I would expect something like `boggle_board.include?("P")` to return a nested array of indices `[[0,0][0,1],[2,1]]`. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing super-elegant comes to mind for me right now.  This seems to work:

```
def indices_of(board, letter)
  indices = []

  board.each_with_index do |ar, i|
    ar.each_with_index do |s, j|
      indices.push([i, j]) if s == letter
    end
  end

  indices
end

boggle_board = [["P", "P", "X", "A"], 
                ["V", "F", "S", "Z"],
                ["O", "P", "W", "N"],
                ["D", "H", "L", "E"]]

indices_of(boggle_board, "P")
# => [[0, 0], [0, 1], [2, 1]]
```

Comment: Thank you! This is much nicer than the solution I came up with. Involved nested while loops...ugh.

Comment: @tlewin Thanks for fixing that typo. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`Matrix#each_with_index`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-i-each_with_index).The below code is more Rubyistic:

```
require "matrix"
m = Matrix[["P", "P", "X", "A"], 
           ["V", "F", "S", "Z"],
           ["O", "P", "W", "N"],
           ["D", "H", "L", "E"]]
ar = []
m.each_with_index {|e, row, col| ar << [row,col] if e == "P"}
ar #=> [[0, 0], [0, 1], [2, 1]]
```

Comment: @Pavlov's_Dawg you can take a look at mine also.. :) Ruby supports `matrix` kind of calculations. :)